# Spring Boot for Kafka - Multiple KafkaStreams config in one app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In spring for kafka stream can we define two configurations in one app?
If we have two `@Bean` for config, like this, how can I use `secondConfig` into the stream?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaStreamConfig {

    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kafkaStreamConfig() {
        var props = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-stream");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

        ....
 
        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondConfig")
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kafkaStreamConfig() {
        var props = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-stream");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "other-machine:9092");

        ....
 
        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }


}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need multiple config?

Comment: Taking message from twondifferent cluster, both need processing that involves same database

Answer (score 1):

Spring will only create one factory bean (from the default configuration bean). For the second one you will need to define a `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` that uses it.